# How do you extract a URL argument from an HTML tag by using Javascript tokens?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Here is a string I want to extract everything after &key=f430a2c1 until &

Is there a way to access this data, then extract the key?

```
<img src="img/index.php?key=f430a2c1&rand=736920" alt=
```

This string exists within the document, and I may need some function to grab it from the src="" area.

Comment: Can you provide more markup ?

Comment: Can you clarify because, everything after ?key=f430a2c1 until & is "", nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing as to what you want, but maybe this?

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
    wanted;

if (images.length) {
    wanted = images[0].src;
    if (wanted) {
        wanted = wanted.split("?");
        if (wanted.length >= 2 && wanted[1].indexOf("&") !== -1) {
            wanted = wanted[1].split("&")[0];
        }
    }
}

if (typeof wanted !== "string") {
    wanted = "";
}

console.log(wanted);
```

Output

```
key=f430a2c1
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/NyDjx/)