# How do I reference the data in a img src="" tag after getElementByID with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to getElementById("game_image") and the TagName is 'img' I want the data within the 'src' tag, specifically the 'key=f430a2c1' token.:

```
<img id="game_image" src="img/index.php?key=f430a2c1&rand=956875" alt="game image." style="padding-right:150px;" />
```

*

```
$("#b_hint").click(function(){
//        var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img"),
//          wanted;
var data = document.getElementById("game_image"), wanted;
wanted = data[1].src;
//    if (images.length) {
//      wanted = images[1].src;
//    if (wanted) {
//       wanted = wanted.split("?");
//       if (wanted.length >= 2 && wanted[1].indexOf("&") !== -1) {
//           wanted = wanted[1].split("&")[0];
//      }
// }
//}

//if (typeof wanted !== "string") {
//    wanted = "";
// }

alert(wanted);
```

Comment: So `data = wanted`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting a URL argument from a HTML tag by using Javascript tokens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556966/extracting-a-url-argument-from-a-html-tag-by-using-javascript-tokens)

Comment: Possible duplicate ??? How about definite clone ? (Same question, same user...[fail]...)

Comment: @ExpertSystem Haha I know, but that's the default text it spits out :)

Comment: @kinesis: Two identical questions, 9 answers, 0 accepted :/

Answer (score 3):

```
wanted = data.src;
```

`getElementById` returns a single element, not a NodeList, so you don't need to use array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
wanted = data.src;
wanted = wanted.substring(wanted.indexOf('?') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the the `src` URL could contain more parameters separated by '&', you can extract `key=...` like this:

```
function getKey(url) {
    var idx1 = url.indexOf("?") + 1;
    if (idx1 == -1) { return ""; }

    var idx2 = url.indexOf("&");
    if (idx2 == -1) { idx2 = url.length; }

    return url.substring(idx1, idx2);
}

$("#b_hint").click(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("game_image");
    var wanted = getKey(img.src);
    ...
```

**NOTE**:
For the `getKey()` function to work properly, the 'key' parameter must come straight ater the '?' (e.g. `...?key=...`, but **not** `...?some=other&key=...`).

Answer (score 0):

See also this regex-powered solution:

```
var regex = new RegExp(".*?\\?.*?\\b(key=[^&]+)");
$("#b_hint").click(function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("game_image").src;
    var wanted = regex.test(src) ? src.match(regex)[1] : "";
    ...
```

This will properly match the `key=<value>` part, even if 'key' is not the first parameter in the query string.

Answer (score -1):

Jquery?!
working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/mpyfQ/8/

```
    var data = $("#game_image").attr("src");
    data = data.substring(data.indexOf('?') + 1);
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer should be InnerHTML.

Comment: Img tags can't have child nodes so they'll never have innerHTML.

Comment: The answer should not be InnerHTML.

Comment: The answer would not be innerHTML